# Why "solve" function produces segmentation fault with OpenStreetMap package in R?

Tags: r, linux

I was using the `spatsurv` package in R and when compiling my code using R in the terminal on Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie), segmentation fault was returned and R was closed. After some debugging, I found out that the problem appears when using `solve` function. In addition, one of the authors of `spatsurv` package suggested me to test the same problem with each imported package. Then, after making that test, the problem was only with `OpenStreetMap` package.

```
library(OpenStreetMap)
x <- solve(diag(1, 1000)) 
# Segmentation fault
```

If I use the solve function before loading OpenStreetMap, I get the following:

```
x <- solve(diag(1, 1000))
library(OpenStreetMap)
x <- solve(diag(1, 1000))
# An irrecoverable stack overflow has occurred.
# Please check if any of your loaded .so files has enabled executable stack (see man page execstack(8))
# Error: segfault from C stack overflow
```

Information of my clean session is below:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

I would like to know how to solve this segmentation fault to be able to use `spatsurv` package.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on Debian Testing (R version 3.2.5).

Comment: At least, I know that it is running in a PC with Debian. I also was using Debian Testing, but I made a clean installation with Debian Jessie thinking that the problem could be because of the testing version. It wasn't.

Comment: In addition, there is no errror if I run the second chunk (`solve`, `library`, `solve`) with `source`. Any idea?